# ie7 and ie6 don't appear to style class names within google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

ie6 and ie7 arent picking up class styling for map overlays (google.maps.OverlayView). has anyone else had this issue and worked it out?

eg i have an overlay like:

```
<div class="cp-map-pin cp-map-pinTboth" style="position: absolute; left: 326px; top: 241px;">
    <div class="cp-map-pin-inner">
        <div class="cp-map-pin-contents">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and ie6 and ie7 arent styling .cp-map-pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the issue! and to make a note for anyone else looking for this:

i was using the following which ie6/7 don't recognise as the class

```
divInner.setAttribute('class', 'classname');
```

i had to change it to

```
divInner.className = 'classname';
```

and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that IE6 has buggy support for multiple class names in CSS: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: thanks for this, i'm aware of the ie6 bugs and use multiple classes independently of each other. good to note though cheers